# Sklearn clustering similar orders

Tags: python, matrix, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a dataset of restaurant invoices, containing the products ordered bye each client.

I've already processed the data and I have the following matrix in csv file:

```
InvoiceID, Product 1, product 2, product 3, product 4, product 5.....
123,       0,         1,         0,         1,         0,       .....
124,       0,         1,         1,         1,         0,       .....
...
```

For each invoice I have an entry in the csv that contains 0 and 1 if the product in represented by column was ordered by the client (0 was not ordered, 1 was ordered).

How do I process this data with sklearn so I can cluster the invoices and get the centroids so I can see what products are in each cluster center?

Thank you!

EDIT:
I have 957 products and a lot of them never were never ordered so I can reduce the matrix (dont know the best way to do it)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure *clustering* is what you need?

It sounds as if **market basket analysis** (and frequent itemset mining) are the way to go.

Most clustering algorithms will assign *every* customer to *exactly* one type, whereas FIM will also detect subsets and overlapping patterns.

Comment: I agree, frequent itemset mining is probably more the way to go. Do you know a good library for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the clustering algorithms in scikit-learn. Take care not to pass it the ID column. You can mask the always zero columns using numpy or pandas.
A good introduction to the clustering methods in scikit-learn can be found in the [user guide](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/clustering.html)